# Как наиболее эффективно подсчитать количество true в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как наиболее эффективно подсчитать количество true в массиве. Массив содежит только true и false.
Мой вариант:

```
let count = arr.reduce((acc,cell_value) => acc + (cell_value ? 1 : 0));
```

Но выглядит очень не читабельно. Я стараюсь держать проект читабельным.
Есть ли более елегантный способ или какая-нибудь встроенная функция для этого?

Comment: проверку можно убрать и сократить до `.reduce((a,c)=>a+c)`. Что имеется ввиду под эффективностью?

Comment: @Grundy, однако, однако! А кто мне про true и false внизу писал?!!! А тут значит можно и integer + bolean, и bolean+ bolean!!! ;-)

Comment: @Grundy да выглядит компактнее, но еще менее читабельно. с фильтром более читабельно тогда

Comment: @Bharata, в моем комментарии нет исходного массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var arr = [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false];
    var count = arr.filter(function(value){return value});
    console.log(count.length);
```

Также, если из вашего ответа удалить стрелочные функции, то тоже будет удобочитаемо.

Comment: _Массив содержит только true и false_

Comment: @Grundy, а у меня они именно так и содержутся! Это же JS!

Comment: _Это же JS!_ - Именно, и в массиве у тебя `1` и `0` - что не является `true` и `false`

Comment: @Grundy, спорим?

Comment: Конечно спорим.

Comment: @Grundy, на что?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77809/discussion-between-grundy-and-bharata).

Comment: @Grundy, исправил ответ для тебя! Радуйся и наслаждайся! :-)

Comment: В принципе с вашей подачей arr.filter(value => value).length уже выглядит лучше чем моя функция.

Comment: Ну и в чём же тут оптимальность?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте

```
let count = arr.filter(Boolean).length
```

Comment: Ну и в чём же тут оптимальность?

Answer (score 1):

```
let count = arr.filter(item => item).length
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а чем данный ответ отличается от двух уже существующих?

Comment: Ну и в чём же тут оптимальность? И вообще, самый старый ответ с filter лучше этого.

Answer (score 0):

1. Наиболее эффективно - руками в цикле.

   ```js
   var a = [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false]

   var res = 0
   for (var x of a) res += x
   console.log(res)
   ```
2. Если всё-таки хочется через методы массива, то reduce намного лучше создания лишнего массива, а boolean к числу приведётся сам:

   ```js
   var a = [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false]

   console.log(a.reduce((r, x) => r+x, 0))
   ```

Comment: Зачем вам отвечать на вопрос 6 летней давности, с 3-мя рабочими ответами?

Comment: @ΝNL993, во-первых, они все одинаковые, во-вторых, ни один из них оптимального решения не предлагает.

Comment: `ни один из них оптимального решения не предлагает. ` -- из вопроса: _Я стараюсь держать проект читабельным. Есть ли более елегантный способ или какая-нибудь встроенная функция для этого?_

Comment: @ΝNL993, во-первых, все варианты одинаково читаемы (кроме того, что в вопросе), восторых, а заголовок _"как наиболее эффективно подсчитать"_ для кого?